Assessing the security of the V2Ray ecosystem and its protocols
I recently came across tools like v2rayNG, described as "A V2Ray client for Android, supporting Xray core and V2Fly core," which function as VPN or proxy clients. These seem to utilize protocols like VMess, VLess, Trojan, REALITY, and Shadowsocks for communicating to servers.
While I'm not very familiar with the V2Ray ecosystem, I noted that some of the protocols can be configured to function without encryption, or do not support it at all. Moreover, protocols like REALITY appear to modify established protocols such as TLS.
On the other hand, it seems that some of these protocols can leverage reasonable AEAD schemes like AES-256-GCM. Despite their popularity, I couldn't find formal verifications or rigorous security assessments for most of these protocols.
Question: As someone who's not an expert in cryptography, I'm curious about the general perception of the security of V2Ray ecosystem (including its various clients and protocols) within the community. What are some key concerns that users, especially those using a restrictive network, should be aware of when using this technology?
